# Mysql UPDATE before first checking if necessary or just UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, optimization, select

I'm using mysql to update a field in a table when a condition is met...

Should I first do a SELECT to see if the condition is met or do I just try to use UPDATE every time, because if the condition is not met, nothing happens.

To be concrete, here is my SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM forum_subscriptions 
WHERE IDTopic=11111 AND IDUser=11111 and status=0
```

I am checking here if I am on forum topic 11111 and if if I (user ID 1) is subscribed to this topic and my status on the subscription is 0 (that means that he didn't yet get email about new post in topic)

So when this is met do:

```
UPDATE forum_subscriptions SET Status=1 where IDTopic=11111 AND IDUser=1
```

Now I am wondering, I always do a select here to query if a user is subscribed to this topic and he has a status that he visited that topic before so any new posts will not trigger new email notification. When he visits the page again, the update is triggered that resets the visit so any new posts will again send him email.

So select is made on every user if he is subscribed or not to test the subscription. Update is made only when necessary.

Is it better to just use the update? To try to update on every page, if he is not subscribed to the topic it will not update anything.

How fast is update that doesn't produce any valid data? How is it made internally, how does update find if there is any record, does it select and then update? If so it would be better to only update because I would achieve same thing without any slowdowns. If the update is more expensive than select I should try to check first and then update if necessary.

This example is a real life example, but the logic behing this update/select is really what I am interested because I do find this kind of a problem more often.

Thanx

**UPDATE:** Thanx both guys, but I do not see on your links if UPDATE is locking even without results or not. As you gave different answers I still don't know what to do.

The subscription table really doesn't need to be myisam, I could change it to InnoDB because I don't have a need to fulltext it. Is this a good solution, to only use update and change this small table to inno? Does mixing table types have any drawbacks?

Comment: Are you asking regarding `InnoDB` or `MyISAM` tables?

Comment: I use myISAM tables but I guess I could use this subscription table to be INNODB as I do not need fulltext on it... Is it smart to change it to innodb and use update only?

Answer (score 2):

You just do the update, with no previous select:

```
UPDATE forum_subscriptions SET Status=1 where IDTopic=11111 AND IDUser=1
```

If the conditions are not met, update will do nothing.
This update is very fast **if** you have an index on `status` and `IDtopic` and `IDuser`!
An empty update is just as fast as an empty select.

If you do the select first, you will just slow things down for no reason.

If you want to know how many rows where updated do a

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT() as rows_affected
```

After doing the update, this will tell you 0 if no rows where updated, or the number of rows updated *(or inserted or deleted, if you used those statements)*.
This function is ultra fast because it just has to fetch one value from memory.

**Workarounds for table locking issues**

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-locking.html

Comment: Thanx a lot, so the update itself if first making a select to see if update at all? I mean, users that aren't subscribers do not really lock myisam table because of this update statement?

Comment: Where do I do SELECT ROW_COUNT()? Right after UPDATE? What if another update took place in between both queries?

Comment: Thanx for the update. But if some other UPDATE somewhere on the site took place in mysql, I would get a wrong ROW_COUNT()?

Comment: @Jerry2, the row_count() is a value per session. If you have a 100 sessions connecting to the database, row_count will only return the number of rows affected for update/delete/insert queries that YOU initiated in YOUR session. and only the rows affected in your latest query.

Comment: Aha, I see, then it is OK. It will always return the right value. I do not need the ROW_COUNT() but it is nice to know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A potential side affect of always calling the `UPDATE` is the locking that needs to be put to insure that no other connection modifies these rows.

- If the table is `MyISAM` - a lock will be places on the he entire table during the search.
- If the table is `InnoDB`, locks will be places on the indexes/gaps.

From the [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html):

> A locking read, an UPDATE, or a DELETE
>   generally set record locks on every
>   index record that is scanned in the
>   processing of the SQL statement. It
>   does not matter whether there are
>   WHERE conditions in the statement that
>   would exclude the row

Comment: So locking is done even if the result is empty, which it is most of the time? This is now really a question of how update is made insternally on mysql 5.6. Does it first select and if it finds a record it updates or it just try to updates and lock even where there are no records.

Comment: @jerry2 Yes. If you are using `InnoDB` tables & have proper indexes designed, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @jerry2 Locks are placed during the *search* of the records that need to be updated.

Comment: @Jerry2: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-locking.html for info on hwo locking works.

Comment: I am using myISAM because I need fulltext search. So it is better to use select and update only as necessary?

Comment: @Jerry, you can update delayed, this will prioritize selects over updates, see the `workarounds for table locks` in my answer.

Comment: If I change table to innodb and use update only, is this a speedy safe way to do it?

Comment: @jerry2 What is the primary key on the table? Is `DTopic` unique? Is the combination `DTopic,IDUser` unique?

Comment: IDTopic is not unique, IDUser is not unique, as the user can be subscribed to many topics and different users can be subscribed to same forum topic. But yes, IDtopic, IDUser IS unique. There is no primary key.